# How to use SymPy to derive commutation relations?

Tags: python, math, sympy, physics, symbolic-math

I'm trying to use SymPy to derive the expression for the commutator of momentum squared and position.  After a lot of trial and error, I came up with this code:

```
from sympy import symbols, simplify, Function, I
from sympy.physics.quantum import Commutator, Operator

hbar = symbols('hbar', real = True, positive = True, constant = True)
r = Operator('r')
p = Operator('p')
psi = Function('\psi')(r)

def p_operator(f):
    return -I*hbar*(Derivative(f, r))

def r_operator(f):
    return r*f

p.apply_operator = p_operator
r.apply_operator = r_operator


(Commutator(r.apply_operator(psi), (p.apply_operator(psi))**2).doit())
```

which results in the error "Can't calculate derivative wrt r."

(I initially was doing `Commutator(r, p.apply_operator(p)**2).doit()`)

If I define `r` as a symbol instead of an operator, or define another symbol variable, `r_sym`, make psi a function of `r_sym` instead and differentiate w.r.t.`r_sym`, that gets rid of the error, but then the code outputs zero, which is wrong -- the correct answer is `2*I*hbar`.

I've tried specifying that `commutative = False` in the definition of `r_sym`, but it still outputs zero.  I've also tried just defining `r` and `p` as generic operators (i.e. not bothering with the `apply_operator` attribute), doing `Commutator(r, p*p).doit()` and then using the `sub` method plug in the expression for `p` and simplify, but that also results in  an output of zero, presumably because it's still treating everything as commutative when I don't want it to.  Hence, it seems like I really do need to define both `r` and `p` as operators, but then I get it complaining it doesn't want to differentiate w.r.t. to an operator.

What's the workaround?  My thought is to just not bother defining `psi` at all and instead to somehow define `p_operator` without an argument, but I don't know how I'd include the derivative at all in that case, as SymPy's `Differentiate` function (and corresponding `diff` method) require an argument.